# Best practice for entering imperial values in a construction-related software

Tags: software, measuring

We're building a mobile app that is used in the construction industry, specifically for designing the 'flashing' of large, commercial sheds; the folded piece of steel that caps the exterior joins of the roof.

We're in Australia, and the widely adopted standard is to just have everything in millimetres (mm). Even though a flashing can be up to 1200mm, all display and input fields in our app are in whole mm values.

We want to adapt the app for the US and I'm curious to find out how imperial measurements are handled in this kind of software. We want to handle lengths from up to 1200mm (3 feet and 11.24 inches) down to, say, 15mm (0.59 inches). Ideally, we'd need accuracy to about 2mm. Concise display is also important (a lot of these values appear on a drawing).

For example, given a length of 449mm, should we go with something like:

- Feet and decimal inches: `1' 5.68"`
- Feet and fractional inches: `1' 5 11/16"`
- Something else?

Even more importantly, what would users expect when entering these values, separate fields for feet, inches, and a selector for the appropriate fraction? Or would feet and inches-with-decimal be adequate?

Some other related questions:

- What's the best practice for using single and double quotes to indicate feet and inches, should there be a comma or space (or nothing) between the two values (e.g. `1',5.68"`, `1' 5.68"` or `1'5.68"`).
- What's the best approach for a concise display of fractional values? The special Unicode character U+2044 FRACTION SLASH looks like the way to go (explained https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55033436/how-to-display-the-fraction-15-16-nicely-in-unicode)

Looking forward to some direction from those non-metric UX implementors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to tape measures we ("imperialists") think in terms of fractional units:

```
1' 5 11/16"
```

...written without commas. However, a dash can be use to distinguish the integer inches from the fractional inches:

```
1' 5-11/16"
```

Provide two fields, one for feet, and a second for inches:

```
____ ft.   ________ in.
```

Allow either fractional or decimal inches input.

---

*Better yet—if space allows...*

Allow for fractional and decimal inputs but convert to metric.

Also allow a value to be entered in the metric field and convert it to fractional imperial IF the denominator is one of: 2, 4, 8, 16, or 32. However if the denominator is not 2, 4, 8, 16, or 32 convert it to decimal.

*Here's how and why...*

Start the process with imperial input, allowing the user to enter either fractional or decimal inches.

**Imperial input:**

Provide two fields, one for feet, and a second for inches:

```
____ ft.   ________ in.
```

But provide a metric field that gets automatically calculated:

```
_1_ ft.   _5_11/16_ in. ( _449_ mm )
```

...and be sure to accommodate if anyone enters a decimal in the inches field:

```
_1_ ft.   _5.68_ in. ( _449_ mm )
```

However...

**Metric input:**

If the user enters a value in the metric field, update the feet and inches field and convert to decimal:

```
_1_ ft.   _5.72_ in. ( _450_ mm )
```

—we'll have to mentally convert `5.72` to nearly `5 3/4` to determine if that works—but overall is less cognitive load because:

```
_1_ ft.   _5_18/25_ in. ( _450_ mm )
```

`5 18/25 in.` is practically incomprehensible.

`.72` is much more easily recognized as almost `.75` and that as `3/4`.

Our tape measure units are: `1/2`, `1/4`, `1/8`, `1/16`, and `1/32`.

Commonly known decimal/fractional associations are: `.75`, `.5`, `.25`, corresponding to `3/4`, `1/2`, and `1/4`.

So, unless the numerator is 2, 4, 8, 16, or 32, it's cognitively easier for "imperialists" to round a decimal to nearest "known" decimal (.75, .5, .25), then to a tape measure unit (3/4, 1/2, and 1/4), and determine whether or not we're in the ballpark.

Comment: Thanks @bloodyKnuckles, this is helpful. Due to screen limitations, we won't ever be displaying the metric and the imperial measurements (always one or the other). The basic gist of what you're saying though seems to be: enter imperial values in feet (whole numbers) and inches (with decimals), but display values in feet, inches and inch-fractions (closest fraction with a denominator of 2, 4, 8 or 16). Would that be right?

Comment: @MickByrne Sorry, allow me to clarify... If someone enters inches in decimal form there's no need to convert to fractional. They know what they're doing. I only recommend converting METRIC to decimal IF the fractional denominator is not one of: 2, 4, 8, 16, 32. I updated my answer—hope that helps.